# Since which version of NodeJS is Crankshaft enabled by default?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, v8

(I think this question needs no body.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

v0.3.2 was the first to bundle V8 3.0.x, all versions after that had Crankshaft enabled on ia32 (but not on x64 or arm).

Versions v0.3.2 - v0.3.7 come with V8 3.0.x. Crankshaft enabled only on ia32.

Versions v0.3.8 - v0.5.0 come with V8 3.1.x. Crankshaft enabled only on ia32.

v0.5.1 was the first to bundle V8 3.4.x: Crankshaft enabled on all architectures (ia32, x64, arm).

(Actually it was enabled since V8 3.2.0 but there was no node.js version that bundled it.)